# Does Laravel Spark Support Stripe Quantities?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-spark

In Laravel Spark, (it's my understanding) you can tie your billing plan to a billing plan already setup in Stripe with code that looks something like this

```
    Spark::plan('Basic', 'provider-id-1')
        ->price(10)
        ->features([
            'First', 'Second', 'Third'
        ]);
```

where `provider-id-1` is the Stripe ID of you billing plan.  The `10` listed as price is used for local display -- the actual price is setup in Stripe.  (if this is incorrect, please let me know)

Does Laravel Spark support [Stripe's concept of quantities](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quantities)?  I don't see anything about this in the docs, but I'm sometimes bad at reading docs.

If not -- has anyone extended Laravel Spark to use quantities.  If so, what was involved?  I assume you'd need to

1. Change the Strip API behavior to send along quantities when subscribing a user
2. Change Laravel display code to display a quantity based pricing
3. More things that didn't occur to me?

If Laravel spark doesn't support quantities, does anyone know which classes/files are responsible for the two items above? (particularly the Stripe API classes)

Comment: This little snippet is also helpful: https://gist.github.com/dillinghamio/7f3b776e0ff1007cc877d63d6aaee10d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, [Spark does not let you set a quantity](https://github.com/laravel/spark/blob/22e838facfd907589619c58f70275ebcbf4f5d76/src/Interactions/Subscribe.php) while subscribing.

However, because Spark uses [Cashier](https://github.com/laravel/cashier) under the hood, and because Cashier [has the concept of quantity](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/58efad0548d307426be6d4efbba0193f49285408/src/SubscriptionBuilder.php#L86), you should be able to either `swap` in your own Subscribe class, or you can possibly do something like this (untested):

```
$subscription = $user->billable->subscription();
$subscription->quantity(5);
$subscription->save();
```

As for the UI, that will have to be custom built.

Comment: Yes, you can use `$subscription->quantity(5)`. I am using this in a SASS application and it works correctly.

Comment: Adding the link form @BrianGlaz above https://gist.github.com/dillinghamio/7f3b776e0ff1007cc877d63d6aaee10d

Comment: I am curious where this code was used, in what Spark file? I am having the same issue.

Comment: This feature is implemented in Spark v6 https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/billing#charging-per-seat